# How to reference Jasmine for VS 2013 Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have created a Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2013 (VS) using Angularjs. I have used npm to add karma and karma-jasmine (among others) to my project. I also installed a VS extension called "Karma Test Adapter" which is great. My jasmine test specs show up in the VS test explorer window.

My Angular VS project Structure:

```
My Solution
  My Project
    app
      controllers
      services
      app.js
      index.html
    bower_components
      ...
    node_modules
      karma
      karma-jasmine
      ...
    scripts
      _references.js
    test
      myCodeSpec.js
    .bowerrc
    bower.json
    gulpfile.js
    karma.conf.jsp
    package.json
```

I can not seem to get VS to do proper intellisense for Jasmine. I have tried using all sorts of paths in the `/// <reference path="..." />` tag at the top of my test*Spec.js file but nothing gives the correct intellisense.

Really this is just a nicety since I could just remember all the syntax but... intellisense is awfully nice.

Has anyone gotten this to work correctly?

Comment: For what its worth - it "broke" as of jasmine version 2.0.  Works fine in 1.3

Comment: I've resorted to using the 1.3 version just for intellisense even though I'm using 2.0   The majority of syntax has stayed the same so its better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download jasmine locally from distro
and then in tools > options > text editor > JavaScript > intellisense > references

Add the link to the jasmine.js

it should get you going

Comment: VS 2013 intellisense is still brain-dead with respect to javascript but this is a solid work-around.

Answer (score 1):

install jasmine.js nuget package and the add a reference of the file inside the top of the document where you need it.

```
/// <reference path=/<path>/jasmine.js/>
```